# How to disable touch scrolling in WinForms for Windows 10?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, touch, tablet

Years ago we have developed a WinForms application that was running with Windows 7, but should now run with Windows 10. This application is used on touch screens.

In Windows 7, the user could only scroll DataGridViews and other things using the scrollbar. Since this application is running with Windows 10, the user can also scroll these controls by swiping/dragging the control.

However, we don't want to change the behavior of this application now it is running with a newer Windows version, so we don't want to have this 'touch scrolling' functionality. Only the scrollbars may be used to scroll.

WPF has better touch support for these kind of things (`PanningMode` on ScrollViewers etc.), but unfortunately we can't migrate this application from WinForms to WPF.

So is there a way to disable this touch scrolling in code for WinForms? Or can it be disabled system wide with a Windows 10 setting or somewhere in the registry?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this right... you want to actively make your app harder to use?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Believe it or not, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague found a solution.

In the registry, find key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch\PanningDisabled` and set it to `1`. Without rebooting, swiping will be disabled.